# Is it possible to rent a bike in one city and drop off in another, when traveling to Vietnam?

Tags: rental, vietnam

I want to rent a motorbike or a mountain bike in Bai Thom (north of Phu Quoc), travel to the south or middle of Phu Quoc, and return it there. Likely we would return it in Duong Dong before catching a flight to Ho Chi Minh City.

Is this possible, or do I have to return the rented bikes at Bai Thom?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any bike-rental companies that operate in multiple cities.  What a lot of tourists do is simply purchase the bike outright -- you can pick up a perfectly serviceable Honda for $300 -- and then sell, give away, or abandon the bike at the end of the trip.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to rent a bike in one city and drop off in another, when traveling to Vietnam?

**It depends,** namely on what cities you want to rent and drop off your bike in.

There are a few one-way rental companies with motorcycles targeted at tourists. The one I saw advertised most often when I was in Vietnam last month was Motorvina. These companies will let you do a one-way rental to and from particular cities, generally those that are major tourist draws.

The towns you've mentioned don't strike me as being particularly large or otherwise highly tourists, so it's quite unlikely that you'll be able to arrange a one-way rental between them.

Most tourists will instead purchase a motorcycle for use while visiting. These bikes are very affordable, and you will often find tourists in Hanoi or HCMC advertising their (sometimes modified for luggage) bikes for sale.